# Convergence of fixed point iteration when $g'(p)=1$.

Tags: self-learning, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson

I am dealing with a function $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$, which has a root $p$ of infinite multiplicity at 0. I am struggling with the convergence rate of the resulting standard Newton fixed point iterate:
\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}&=x_n-\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x_n^2}}}{2x_n^{-3}e^{-\frac{1}{x_n^2}}}\\
g(x_n)&=x_n-\frac{x_n^3}{2}
\end{align*}
I believe this works as an iterate in theory. i.e. it maps $[-1,1]$ to a subset of $[-1,1]$ and I can show that basin of attraction is $|x|<2$. However, heuristically it seems that this should never converge, considering the "spider plot" of $y=x$ and $g(x)$. (I can't post the image because I don't have enough rep). Basically $g'(x)\approx1$ anywhere near $p$ and $g'(p)=1\nless 0$.

Let's assume we start at $x_0=1$. Can someone offer an argument for how long it will take to converge to within a tolerance $\delta$ or an argument as to why it won't converge?

Comment: @tomi nailed the picture I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems easier to understand the slow rate of convergence by transforming the process into an iteration on $y = 1/x$ and observing the *divergence* to infinity.

That is, with $y_n = 1/x_n$ the iteration can be rewritten as:

$$ y_{n+1} \gets y_n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2y_n^2} \right)^{-1}
 = y_n\left( \frac{2y_n^2}{2y_n^2 - 1} \right)
 = y_n\left(1 + \frac{1}{2y_n^2 - 1}\right)
 = y_n + \frac{1}{2y_n - y_n^{-1}} $$

So for large $y_n$ we have $y_{n+1} - y_n \approx 0.5 y_n^{-1}$.  One therefore expects that if $y$ were treated as a continuous function of index $n=t$, the behavior would be approximately that of the solution of differential equation:

$$ y'(t) = 0.5 y^{-1} $$

namely $y(t) = \sqrt{t + c}$.

On this basis we would predict that for $x = 1/y$ to reach $10^{-5}$ (equivalently, for $y$ to reach $10^5$) would require something like $10^{10}$ iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an image for you...

[image]

You know, it seems to me that it is converging, albeit slowly.

With fixed point iterations we know that the speed of convergence depends of the magnitude of $g'(x)$.

This can be shown by using the first order approximation of $g(x+\epsilon)=g(x)+\epsilon g'(x)$.

Eventually we get $\epsilon_{r+1}=g'(x)\epsilon_r$,

... so we are sure that the errors will decrease if $\left |g'(x)\right|<1$

This does not take into acount what happens if a first order approximation is invalid, nor does it say what will happen if $\left |g'(x)\right|\ge1$. It';s easy to assune that the method will diverge, but by no means certain.

So suppose we know that $g'(x)=1$.

Then $g(x+\epsilon)\approx g(x)+\epsilon g'(x)+\frac 12 \epsilon^2 g''(x)=g(x)+\epsilon +\frac 12 \epsilon^2 g''(x)$

Since $x_{r+1}=g(x_r)$

$x+\epsilon_{r+1}=g(x+\epsilon_r)$

$x+\epsilon_{r+1}=g(x)+\epsilon_r +\frac 12 \epsilon_r^2 g''(x)$

But at the root $g(x)=x$, so

$x+\epsilon_{r+1}=x+\epsilon_r +\frac 12 \epsilon_r^2 g''(x)$

$\epsilon_{r+1}=\epsilon_r +\frac 12 \epsilon_r^2 g''(x)$

What this means is that the error will increase if $g''(x)>0$ and decrease if $g''(x)<0$

You have $g(x)=x-\frac {x^3}2$

$g'(x)=1-\frac {3x^2}2$

$g''(x)=-3x$

So $g''(x)<0$ as required provided $x>0$.

In fact $\epsilon_{r+1}=\epsilon_r +\frac 12 \epsilon_r^2 g''(x)=\epsilon_r +\frac 12 \epsilon_r^2 (-3\epsilon_r)$

$\epsilon_{r+1}=\epsilon_r \left(1 -\frac 32 \epsilon_r^2 \right)$

Now to consider the number of steps required for convergence...

Suppose that after $n$ steps we have reached a point where $\epsilon_n=10^{-k}$ and that after another $m$ steps we will reach the point where $\epsilon_{n+m}=10^{-(k+1)}$.

We know that $\epsilon_{n+1}=\epsilon_n \left(1 -\frac 32 10^{-2k} \right)$

and that $\epsilon_{n+m+1}=\epsilon_{n+m} \left(1 -\frac 32 10^{-2(k+1)} \right)$

$\epsilon_{n} \left(1 -\frac 32 10^{-2k} \right)^m \le \epsilon_{n+m} \le \epsilon_{n} \left(1 -\frac 32 10^{-2(k+1)} \right)^m$

$\left(1 -\frac 32 10^{-2k} \right)^m \le \frac 1{10} \le \left(1 -\frac 32 10^{-2(k+1)} \right)^m$

$m \log \left(1 -\frac 32 10^{-2k} \right)\ge \log (\frac 1{10}) \ge m \log \left(1 -\frac 32 10^{-2(k+1)} \right)$

$\frac {\log (\frac 1{10}) }{ \log \left(1 -\frac 32 10^{-2k} \right)}\le m \le \frac {\log (\frac 1{10})}{ \log \left(1 -\frac 32 10^{-2(k+1)} \right)}$

Using Excel, I found the following:

It should take fewer than $1.54 \times 10^{10}$ steps to move from $\epsilon=10^{-4}$ to $\epsilon=10^{-5}$

It should take fewer than $1.54 \times 10^{12}$ steps to move from $\epsilon=10^{-5}$ to $\epsilon=10^{-6}$

It should take fewer than $1.54 \times 10^{14}$ steps to move from $\epsilon=10^{-6}$ to $\epsilon=10^{-7}$

Beyond here Excel starts to struggle with calculating the logarithms, but a clear patter is visible: it takes about 100 times as many steps to get the next decimal place.

Comment: I agree. It does seem that it converges. I also convinced myself of this by plugging the algorithm into MatLab and watching it run for about a million iterations ($|x_n|$ decreased on every iteration). However, I am specifically interested in _how many_ iterations will be required for a given tolerance, even if the argument is hand-wavy. In the MatLab implementation, $|x_n|$ never decreased below about $10^{-4}$ even for ginormous (rigorous term) $n$. What $n$ would it take to get to $10^-5$, for example?

Comment: @hardmath yes, thanks - silly of me - was tired when writing that...